# Open Multiple Taskmanagers

Tags: windows, taskmanager

Is there a way to open multiple taskmanagers in Windows 10? 
I trie this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61970/Running-multiple-instances-of-Task-Manager
but it doesn't work

```
@echo off

start "taskmgr" "%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe"
start "taskmgr" "%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe"
start "taskmgr" "%windir%\system32\taskmgr.exe"
```

Comment: Is this about programmatically running multiple instances? Otherwise it sounds like this question should be moved to Superuser.

Comment: Yes, I want to create a script and when I run it multiple  (3) instances of taskmanage must open

Comment: Fair enough. But then you need to add more details about what exactly you have tried and exactly how it failed. "Doesn't work" questions are usually not popular on here :)

Comment: I edited my original post this is what I have now, but it only starts 1 taskmgr